# Post data from button value to views in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a button in my template and I need to post the value of the button to my views. Unfortunately, my request.POST returns 'None'. How can I retrieve the information from my HTML template?
Thank you.

My template:

```
{% extends 'vocab/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'card' %}" method="POST">

    {% for document in documents %}
        <button type ='submit' value="{{ document.file }}" class='btn btn-outline-info' > 
{{document.file}} </button>
    {% endfor %}
</form> 

{% endblock content %}
```

My view:

```
def card_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    context = {'request.POST':request.POST}
    return render(request, 'vocab/card.html', context)
```

Comment: You just need to give your button a name, then it'll send the value. You can have multiple buttons with the same name, the value of the clicked button will be sent.

Comment: like 
<button name = 'button' type ='submit' value="{{ document.file }}" class='btn btn-outline-info' > ?
and then what should I do in my views?

Comment: The value will be in request.POST['button'] and you can do whatever you need to. If you want to validate the input you can use a Form to do that for you too.

Comment: it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `name` as attribute in button. `name` is like Key in python dictionary while `value` is the value of the Key.
Therefore, by using `name` you can obtain the ```value``

```
context = {'request.POST' : request.POST['name']}
```